# ASP.NET MVC - how to get a full path to an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Inside of a View can I get a full route information to an action?

If I have an action called DoThis in a controller MyController. Can I get to a path of `"/MyController/DoThis/"`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You mean like using the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) method on the Url helper:

```
<%= Url.Action("DoThis", "MyController") %>
```

or in Razor:

```
@Url.Action("DoThis", "MyController")
```

which will give you a relative url (`/MyController/DoThis`).

And if you wanted to get an absolute url (`http://localhost:8385/MyController/DoThis`):

```
<%= Url.Action("DoThis", "MyController", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null) %>
```

Answer (score 11):

Some days ago, I wrote a blog post about that very topic (see [How to build absolute action URLs using the UrlHelper class](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/Archive/2011/06/30/how-to-build-absolute-action-urls-using-the-urlhelper-class)). As Darin Dimitrov mentioned: `UrlHelper.Action` will generate absolute URLs if the `protocol` parameter is specified explicitly.

However, I suggest to write a custom extension method for the sake of readability:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method by using
/// the specified action name, controller name and route values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">The URL helper.</param>
/// <param name="actionName">The name of the action method.</param>
/// <param name="controllerName">The name of the controller.</param>
/// <param name="routeValues">The route values.</param>
/// <returns>The absolute URL.</returns>
public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url,
    string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null)
{
    string scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;

    return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
}
```

The method can then be called like this: `@Url.AbsoluteAction("SomeAction", "SomeController")`